# How to show text box in html which is declared in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I had written JavaScript function to add text boxes with on click function. Here i need to show text boxes wherever i want in the page. The textbox code written in p tag with innerHTML but i need to show text boxes in html.

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">

    <div class="row">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-10">&nbsp;</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" id="div">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="field_div">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" onclick="add_field();"></span>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-12">Child
                </label>
            <div class="col-md-12" I need to show text box here instead in javascript </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <script>
        function add_field() {
            var total_text = document.getElementsByClassName("input_text");
            total_text = total_text.length + 1;
            document.getElementById("field_div").innerHTML = document.getElementById("field_div").innerHTML +
                "<p id='input_text" + total_text + "_wrapper'><input type='text' class='input_text' id='input_text" + total_text + "' placeholder='Enter Text'><input type='text' class='form-control input_text' id='input_text" + total_text + "' placeholder='Enter Text'><input type='button' value='Remove' onclick=remove_field('input_text" + total_text + "');></p>";
        }

        function remove_field(id) {
            document.getElementById(id + "_wrapper").innerHTML = "";
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Your question was edited so I have edited the answer you can check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the text box in incorrect `div`. Simply specify the `id = 'childDiv'` in the lower div and get the text box there.

```js
function add_field() {
    var total_text = document.getElementsByClassName("input_text");
    total_text = total_text.length + 1;
    document.getElementById("childDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("childDiv").innerHTML +
        "<p id='input_text" + total_text + "_wrapper'><input type='text' class='input_text' id='input_text" + total_text + "' placeholder='Enter Text'><input type='text' class='form-control input_text' id='input_text" + total_text + "' placeholder='Enter Text'><input type='button' value='Remove' onclick=remove_field('input_text" + total_text + "');></p>";
}

function remove_field(id) {
    document.getElementById(id + "_wrapper").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">

    <div class="row">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-10">&nbsp;</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" id="div">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="field_div">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" onclick="add_field();">+</span>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-12">Child
             </label>
            <div id='childDiv' class="col-md-12"> I need to show text box here instead in javascript </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-12">Child
            </label>
      <button onclick="add_field()">Add</button>
      <div class="col-md-12" id="field_div"> I need to show text box here instead in javascript </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<script>
  function add_field() {
    var total_text = document.getElementsByClassName("input_text");
    total_text = total_text.length + 1;
    document.getElementById("field_div").innerHTML = document.getElementById("field_div").innerHTML +
      "<p id='input_text" + total_text + "_wrapper'><input type='text' class='input_text' id='input_text" + total_text + "' placeholder='Enter Text'><input type='text' class='form-control input_text' id='input_text" + total_text + "' placeholder='Enter Text'><input type='button' value='Remove' onclick=remove_field('input_text" + total_text + "');></p>";
  }

  function remove_field(id) {
    document.getElementById(id + "_wrapper").innerHTML = "";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Is this what you want?